# On Azure, Is there a way to use shared tier with custom domain and ssl?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a dotnet website on Azure App Service, with a custom domain and their generated SSL cert. I get about a dozen hits a day (LOW traffic). The service level that azure requires is a B1 which includes the ssl cert. and custom domain, but $70 a month seems crazy high for the amount of traffic.

Is there any alternatives/solutions/workarounds to use the shared tier level with custom domain and SSL to have a server in the $20 range instead? I have looked at cloudflare, but still azure won't allow their ssl on any lower levels tiers.

I suppose an alternative is aws or google, but I imagine they have the same pricing? plus, I like the integrated tools with dotnet and Azure :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternatives/solutions/workarounds to use the shared tier
> level with custom domain and SSL to have a server in the $20 range
> instead?

No, As per the current [Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) To create custom domains & custom TLS/SSL bindings or enable client certificates for your App Service app, your App Service plan must be in the **Basic** and above tier ( Standard, Premium, or Isolated tier). It is the ASP (App Service Plan) tier.

- Alternatively, As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65679749/15968720) SO  thread, you can use Azure front-door service Create Linux-based proxy server, and setup proxy and use it as a ssl-termination.
- CloudFlare Free plan comes with a free SSL certificate. So essentially your traffic is SSL secured.

For more information you can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279450/ssl-on-azure-shared-plan) thread.